# ICU Collator locale falls to 'root' in deployed server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locale, collation, icu

Collator locale falls to 'root' in cloud deployed application server but works fine while testing in localhost. We are trying to compare and sort based on Swedish locale using [ffi-icu](https://github.com/erickguan/ffi-icu)  Rubygem.

Collator.locale is 'sv' in localhost but 'root' in deployed server. We are not able to debug further in code. Does anyone know in what situation the locale will be set to root or if this is dependant on any other configuration? Is there a way to override Collator.locale?

I tried setting Collator.locale = 'sv' but I get an error saying method undefined.